# Disable the right-click mouse button function in Windows 10 (via registry keys/ GPO?)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy, regedit

I'm hoping someone can help me with how to disable the right mouse / right click button in Windows 10 for a specified group of machines/ users (all using Windows 10).

My objective is to disallow all forms of copy / paste for all users, for a specified set of machines (or users, as I can create an AD group for either one). I've already disabled the snipping tool and Windows hotkeys as well as **NoViewContextMenu** (the latter only disables the context menu for the Desktop and File Explorer but doesn't actually disable the right click function itself).

The background here is that as my users are handling confidential data and don't need to be able to do anything other than log in and take calls, I need to disable any way to use Ctrl+C or Ctrl+V, as well as disable the right-click button (because Copy and Paste are options via that menu as well, for various applications). This is in addition to other controls in place.

I have already created a Scancode Map key in Registry with the following value (which disables the Print Screen key): **0000000000000000040000002AE037E0000037E00000540000000000**

What I'm looking to do is combine that with (a) disabling both the Right Ctrl and Left Ctrl keys as well as (b) disabling the right mouse button. I have been doing some research, and I think the combined binary value for the Scancode Map key as I want to create it (to disable print screen, Left Ctrl, Right Ctrl, and Right-click/ context menu may be this:

**0000000000000000070000002AE037E0000037E00000540000001D0000001DE000005DE000000000**

Is anyone able to confirm that's accurate? Or any other thoughts? Thank you!!

Comment: With [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) this would be easy.

Comment: Don't forget the print screen key on the keyboard. In the end it would be more secure if the confidential data could only be accessed within a virtual machine that does not allow data transmission from guest to host OS.

Comment: I don't have that option. The requirements are that this will be completed for the Windows 10 machines they use, and I'm not allowed to use third-party software (e.g., AutoHotKey) . . . any additional thoughts?

Comment: .. don't forget to find some way to disable [mouse keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer-9e0c72c8-b882-7918-8e7b-391fd62adf33). And people shouldn't be allowed to take their cell phone with them: they could photograph the screen. In short: if you don't trust people, don't allow them to see confidential information. if they have a fully working copy of windows, someone will find a way to copy information.

Comment: @1NN - yes, thank you! Do you know of a way to disable the right mouse key? I'm looking for how to disable both the built-in right mouse button, where that exists, as well as the external right-mouse key. Any insights are greatly appreciated!